# postgresql 13 sync replication - does primary complete flushing to local before sending wal to slaves?

Tags: pgpool, postgresql-13

In a pgpool-II 4.2 and postgresql 13 environment:
3 servers (each hosting a pgpool and a postgresql)

I understand we can set the below parameter for different durability's.
synchronous_commit = off, local, on, remote_write, or remote_apply

My question is that when I set it to something beyond "local" document implies the wal information will not even be sent to slaves until the local is flushed.

My question is why not the below 2 start in parallel

1. local flush starts
2. sending wal info. to slaves

because this would save some time by doing these in parallel, correct?  Or please let me know my understanding is off?

The other question is that does pgpool-II simplify the postgresql failover and failback?  And is it reliable?  Is there some real life examples of setups and comments on this?  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What if the local flushing of the WAL fails for some reason? Then the standby would receive WAL records that are not in sync with the primary server

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @a_horse_with_no_name!  In that case I hope postgres will decide it's a broken transaction and notify the client so, then client can resubmit the txn.  Or simply ignore it and move on.